# Connecting urls using Python's urllib2

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I'm scraping some stock information using urllib2.

Some of my codes are as followings.

```
    cap_url = "http://wisefn.stock.daum.net/company/c1010001.aspx?cmp_cd=%s" % code
    cap_req = urllib2.Request(cap_url)
    cap_data = urllib2.urlopen(cap_req).read()
    ~
    ~
    ~
    depr_url = "http://wisefn.stock.daum.net/company/cF3002.aspx?cmp_cd=%s&frq=Q&rpt=ISM&finGubun=MAIN" % code
    depr_req = urllib2.Request(depr_url)
    depr_data = urllib2.urlopen(depr_req).read()
    ~
    ~
    ~
    transaction_url = "http://www.shinhaninvest.com/goodicyber/mk/1206.jsp?code=%s" % code
    transaction_data = urllib2.urlopen(transaction_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(transaction_data, fromEncoding="utf-8")
```

As you know, %s is stock code. With given stock code, I'm scraping all of stock information. Total number of stock codes are over 1,600. Then I write gathered information to Excel with xlwt.

However, I can't get connecton to some url or get informationm for those I can conncet manually typing that url.

What's the problem? And how can I speed up scraping pages?

Comment: it's quite likely the people you are scraping from are turning off your connection when you exceed their limits, whatever they are. I'm sure you are not the first person to try this....

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now I consider proxy server to exceed connection limits.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check robots.txt file of the website. It most likely prohibit native python user-agent. So you may consider changing user-agent of urllib2. 
Second. The website content might be generated by JavaScript, and if so, urllib2 can not evaluate it. For this purpose you can use Selenium driver, or PyQt framework or similar.